# Android check if value equals to the values in Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a ArrayList tokens; I am adding values to the array with a listView click. 
Before i add the value to array i check if the value already exist array. 
I remove the value is it exists else i will add the the value

This is how i have done, but the values are not being added to the array

```
ArrayList<String> tokens;
tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
...
....
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String selectedtoken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ContactToken"));

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                if (tokens.get(i).equals(id_To_Search)) {
                    tokens.remove(i);
                }
                else {
                    tokens.add(selectedtoken );
                }
            }
    }
...
...
Log.i("array: ", tokens.toString()); // No values in the array
```

Comment: i would suggest use a set and then convert the set to the arraylist when you are done,it would be much easier

Answer (score 4):

You are not adding when you initially have 0 tokens.

Change to:

```
boolean removed = false;
for (Iterator<String> iter = tokens.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    if (iter.next().equals(id_To_Search)) {
        iter.remove();
        removed = true;
    }
}
if(!removed) {
   tokens.add(selectedtoken);
}
```

Comment: That will fail with a ConcurrentModificationException in many cases... and it will *always* have the selected token at the end.

Comment: I've corrected the 2nd but the 1st ehhh, it all on the UI thread

Comment: Just because it's in one thread doesn't mean you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918

Comment: Actually, my mistake - you're not using an enhanced for loop, so you won't get that error. But you *will* skip over entries at the moment. (If you remove entry 0, you're then not going to look at the "new" entry 0...)

Comment: Thank you, I've changed in accordance.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check the existence using `contains` method.

```
if(!tokens.contains(id_To_Search)){
    tokens.add(selectedtoken);
} else {
    tokens.remove(selectedtoken);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're checking for each element in your array if it's the item you're going to store/delete, and then doing the proper operation.

You should find first if you're element exists in the whole array, and then adding or deleting it.

Try something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String selectedtoken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ContactToken"));

            if (tokens.contains(id_To_Search)) {     
               tokens.remove(id_To_Search);

            }
            else {
                tokens.add(id_To_Search);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is empty, you never go into the loop, so you'll never call `add`. If you *do* have any tokens to start with, you're either adding or removing the new token *for each existing token* which isn't what you want.

I suspect you want:

```
int existingIndex = tokens.indexOf(selectedToken);
if (existingIndex == -1) {
   tokens.add(selectedToken);
} else {
   tokens.remove(existingIndex);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Set<String>` with:

```
// Speculatively try to remove it... and add it if you couldn't remove
boolean removed = tokens.remove(selectedToken);
if (!removed) {
   tokens.add(selectedToken);
}
```

Also note that you're currently testing for `id_To_Search` but then adding `selectedToken` - this answer assumes you actually meant to use `selectedToken` in both places.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will not execute when tokens.size() is 0.
So you'll never add a token because initially the token list is empty.